# Resetting all scripts on PJAX page change

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pjax

If I have different pages that I fetch using *PJAX*, the scripts I use one the first page I access persist to the second, and any page accessed after that through *PJAX*.

I've tried resetting functions, and things of the sort, which is too much work. Is it possible that on *PJAX* page change I can reset all Javascript bindings?

Is partial per-page Javascript possible? (such as retaining *jQuery* on page change but removing other scripts that are per-page)

Since a Javascript file can be referenced just by appending a `<script>` tag, can the opposite be done? (I know that removing that script tag doesn't remove the script)

Comment: Please don't codify non-code.

Comment: If you want to reset the page entirely, what's wrong with a good old-fashioned hyperlink?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The outer frame of the page is already loaded, and the Javascript in the frame doesn't need to be loaded again. Therefore I'm not actually trying to reset the page, I'm looking to replace the inner HTML frame with content, then have the Javascript of the inner frame loaded along with the content, while removing traces of the previous inner frame.

Comment: The documentation does have page unload/load events, but I do not know how to totally remove a Javascript files' scripts from the browser except for just overwriting the functions and unsetting any things like setInterval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner "frames" should not contain any Javascript. You should place all your Javascript in functions that are available at the very top level of your page, and then you can hook in to page changes using [the PJAX API](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax/blob/master/README.md) to enable/disable functionality as appropriate.

Comment: I thought a bit about that, and it appears to be the only practical way. Thanks.

Comment: Well it's also the best and cleanest way. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Need your help. Would I need to serve all js for all pages at the initial page load itself? But what if there is different initialization code (event listners' binding, plugin inits etc) for each page. I would need to identify the current page and then trigger the corresponding init function?

Comment: Any progress on this? Dealing with the exact same issue. I have js files for each page. These files often contain bindings to buttons that can occur on multiple pages, but the function is different each time... Loading all at initial page load will break things AND it would be slow loading everything...?!

Comment: @Brainfeeder: Why would it break things? Is your code not properly namespaced? And it won't be "slow" because you already have a single, minified script file for your web application, right? It is like 2KB and only needs to be loaded once and then it's cached, for your entire site. That's pretty fast.

Comment: All general code is in a single file .. Yes.. But this application is a large administration app for a hosting company. Eg: #btn-edit-status has bindings at the invoice,offer,order,...-pages but the function is sligtly different each time. If I load these variations all at once things will get wierd..

Comment: And yes I could change the name of the buttons to something like #btn-edit-invoice-status etc.. But that way I can't reuse the html template like we do now.

Comment: If you can have conflicts like that then you have done it wrong :) Improve your variable naming and use scopes. You know elements can be accessed according to ancestry? e.g. `#some-parent #some-child`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes but that would mean those bindings stay in memory when another page is loaded. I rather reuse them. The jquery loaded per page in separate external files or related to action buttons used in a table. And so it seems I'm not the only one having a problem with the way pjax is handling the newly loaded external scripts. https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax/issues/331

Comment: @Brainfeeder: Still not seeing the issue. Remove the bindings if you want to. Don't if you don't. There is no problem here.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Maybe I should have mentioned this is not a native JavaScript app. It is a CodeIgniter based application. It's comon to have seperate script files mixed with inline script. Sometimed CodeIgniter even will inject JavaScript based on which form element was used. Anyways, I solved it with a fork of pjax by the Yii development team.